# Switch between tabs from different tab groups in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it able to switch between tabs from different groups? Because now if I create two tabs groups and start switching (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>) it will start switching tabs within group (not tab from one group to the tab in other group).

I have tried with `workbench.action.openNextRecentlyUsedEditor` but literally nothing is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an open feature request that complains about the unexpected behavior of `workbench.action.openNextRecentlyUsedEditor`:

[workbench.action.openNextRecentlyUsedEditor does not behave as expected (#37366)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/37366)

Note that it's not that the command doesn't do anything, but that it only does something if there's still another editor left in the recently used list (so it doesn't work as a toggle like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> does).

Answer (score 30):

First, you can use `Ctrl` +`<group number>` to shift the focus to the group you wanted. Then you can use `Ctrl` + `Tab` to shift between the tabs within that group.

[image: Command to shift the focus to group 1 in the command palette]

Let's say I have 2 groups open and I wanted to shift the focus to group 2. I use `Ctrl` + `2`. Later, I can focus on different tabs within group 2 using `Ctrl` + `Tab`.

(Ref) Other related shortcuts are here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_editorwindow-management

Comment: Also, to switch between the tabs with in a group, use `Alt + <tab number>` . For example, if you want to directly switch to a 4th tab in the current group, use `Alt + 4`.

Comment: It is also possible to use `Ctrl + Page-up` and `Ctrl + Page-down`

Comment: Note that you can't use the numpad keys, but the alphanumeric keys.

Comment: For Mac users it it will be `Command + <tab number>` on the first step, to move to the specified tab group ;)

Answer (score 1):

In my version (v1.83.0 for Linux), the default shortcut key for that is `Ctrl + K, Ctrl + arrow key`.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me as of 29 Mar 2022;

```
workbench.action.focusLeftGroup
workbench.action.focusRightGroup
```

These are in effect similar to tabbing left or right.

I set custom commands with:

```
[alt+l, alt+g] 
[alt+r, alt+g]
```

respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following actions set to custom key bindings:

`workbench.action.navigateLeft`

`workbench.action.navigateRight`

`workbench.action.navigateUp`

`workbench.action.navigateDown`

They tab between the currently displayed files in each editor group.

Answer (score 0):

I just what to mention it since I didn't see it.

If you want to keep the default workflow of VScode, with a pop-up menu of must reason tabs in a group, but have it work for must reason tabs in all groups.

Just switch from using

```
workbench.action.quickOpenPreviousRecentlyUsedEditorInGroup
```

to using

```
workbench.action.quickopenPreviousRecentlyUsedEditor
```

Base on how I read the original question, this was what Gama11 was looking for